# Discord.py pagination

Tags: python, pagination, discord, bots, discord.py

So i want to make embeds be paginated so it can change upon reacting to an emoji i found a project called [disputils](https://pypi.org/project/disputils/) which made the process a lot easier, but it supports texts and is there anyway i can include pictures in this code(the documentation has no examples or says that pictures can be embedded any help would be appreciated):

```
@bot.command()
async def paginate(ctx):
    embeds = [
        Embed(title="test page 1", description="This is just some test content!", color=0x115599),
        Embed(title="test page 2", description="Nothing interesting here.", color=0x5599ff),
        Embed(title="test page 3", description="Why are you still here?", color=0x191638)
    ]

    paginator = BotEmbedPaginator(ctx, embeds)
    await paginator.run()
```

i also have tried to use embed.set_image but i get an error `positional argument follows keyword argument (<unknown>, line 12)`(it highlights the embed.set_image)

Comment: How exactly have you tried using `embed.set_image`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`Embed.set_image`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Embed.set_image) on a separate variable and then including that variable on the list of embeds:

```py
@bot.command()
async def paginate(ctx):
    e = Embed(title="test page 1", description="foo", color=0x115599)
    e.set_image(url="foo.png")
    
    embeds = [
        e,
        Embed(title="test page 2", description="bar", color=0x5599ff)
    ]

    paginator = BotEmbedPaginator(ctx, embeds)
    await paginator.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is to describe the embeds outside the list. It should work brilliantly, as it did for me. I included a thumbnail and image option, as I wasn't sure what you meant by "image".

Make sure you did `pip install disputils` in the terminal before you try to put the code into your file.

Here's the code:

```py
import discord
from disputils import BotEmbedPaginator, BotConfirmation, BotMultipleChoice


bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.command()
async def testing(ctx):
    Embed1 = discord.Embed(title="Title", description="Description", color=0x000000)
    Embed1.set_image(url="https://external-preview.redd.it/mu4xWSMFJroZUimyZY4vvjloaAnmzXTh1O2QI_TFlzc.jpg?width=960&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=e042f61d74a80c4bf3f170b9628c14ef56bac427")
    Embed1.set_thumbnail(url="https://external-preview.redd.it/mu4xWSMFJroZUimyZY4vvjloaAnmzXTh1O2QI_TFlzc.jpg?width=960&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=e042f61d74a80c4bf3f170b9628c14ef56bac427")
    Embed2 = discord.Embed(title="Title", description="Description", color=0x000000)
    Embed2.set_image(url="https://external-preview.redd.it/mu4xWSMFJroZUimyZY4vvjloaAnmzXTh1O2QI_TFlzc.jpg?width=960&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=e042f61d74a80c4bf3f170b9628c14ef56bac427")
    Embed2.set_thumbnail(url="https://external-preview.redd.it/mu4xWSMFJroZUimyZY4vvjloaAnmzXTh1O2QI_TFlzc.jpg?width=960&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=e042f61d74a80c4bf3f170b9628c14ef56bac427")
    Embed3 = discord.Embed(title="Title", description="Description", color=0x000000)
    Embed3.set_image(url="https://external-preview.redd.it/mu4xWSMFJroZUimyZY4vvjloaAnmzXTh1O2QI_TFlzc.jpg?width=960&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=e042f61d74a80c4bf3f170b9628c14ef56bac427")
    Embed3.set_thumbnail(url="https://external-preview.redd.it/mu4xWSMFJroZUimyZY4vvjloaAnmzXTh1O2QI_TFlzc.jpg?width=960&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=e042f61d74a80c4bf3f170b9628c14ef56bac427")
    embeds = [Embed1, Embed2, Embed3]
    paginator = BotEmbedPaginator(ctx, embeds)
    await paginator.run()
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that this is simply a more detailed description of @heitor 's Answer.